# Remove semicolon and brackets from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

i have a string like this:

```
{
    Result1 = G;
    "Result2" = "";
    Result3 = "1.03";
    Result4 = 6212753389;
}
```

how i get result like this:

```
    Result1 = G
    Result2 = 
    Result3 = 1.03
    Result4 = 6212753389
```

**NOTE:** i am trying all suggestion of `NSCharacterSet`.

please help me and thank in advance.

Comment: what efforts you have done so far? please share it also

Comment: @PPL wait update those solution

Comment: try replacing characters programtically

Comment: @Vinodh how to  replacing characters programmatically?

Comment: what you expect in output ?

Comment: That seems to be the `description` of a `NSDictionary` to me. Why do you have the `description` of a `NSDictionary` instead of having the `NSDictionary` reference/pointer? If you had it, it would be so much easier to iterate it and print it as you wish: `NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];for (id aKey in myDict){[str appendFormat:@"\t%@ = %@\n", aKey, myDict[aKey]];} NSLog(@"%@", str);`

Comment: @RealmOfFire please refer  for https://stackoverflow.com/a/24201206/1142743

Comment: thanks guys i got solution from larme`s reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong question, or better said: wrong approach or wrong interpretation of your issue.
Don't worry, that's okay, I'll explain why.

This is the typical result of:

```
NSString *str = [myDict description];
```

Or

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myDict]; //(which relies on `description` method of `NSDictionary`, that's just an hidden call.
```

See the doc:

> NSString uses a format string whose syntax is similar to that used by
>   other formatter objects. It supports the format characters defined for
>   the ANSI C function printf(), plus %@ for any object (see String
>   Format Specifiers and the IEEE printf specification). If the object
>   responds to descriptionWithLocale: messages, NSString sends such a
>   message to retrieve the text representation. Otherwise, it sends a
>   description message. Localizing String Resources describes how to work
>   with and reorder variable arguments in localized strings.
>   [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Almost never relies on `description`, that's more for Debugging purpose. For instance, in my experience, Apple changed at least once the description of an object. In ExternalAccessory.framework, you could get the MAC Address of a device with `description` (which is not the politic of Apple), but only on certain iOS version, and once the error spotted, it was removed. So if you had code relying on it, bad luck.

What you want is a custom "print" of your `NSDictionary`.
What you can do:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (id aKey in myDict)
{ 
    [str appendFormat:@"\t%@ = %@\n", aKey, myDict[aKey]];
}
```

This add an extra "\n" at the end of the `NSString`. You can remove it, or use instead of `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id aKey in myDict)
{ 
    NSString *aLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@ = %@", aKey, myDict[aKey]];
    [array addObject:aLine];
}
NSString *str = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Side note: Why do "Result2" had quotes discussions:
[Why do some dictionary keys have quotes and others don't when printing from debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187201/why-do-some-dictionary-keys-have-quotes-and-others-dont-when-printing-from-debu)

[Why does string show up in NSDictionary with quotes, but others don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520486/why-does-string-show-up-in-nsdictionary-with-quotes-but-others-dont)

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {
var pureString: String {
    return self.removeCharsFromString(arr: ["{", "}", ";", "\""])
}

func removeCharsFromString(arr: [String]) -> String {
    var str = self
    for char in arr {
        str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: String(char), with: "")
    }
    return str
}
}
```

**Usage**

```
let str = """
{
Result1 = G;
"Result2" = "";
Result3 = "1.03";
Result4 = 6212753389;
}
"""
print(str.pureString)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
    Swift:

```
let str = "{ Result1 = G; \"Result2\" = \"\"; Result3 = \"1.03\"; Result4 = 6212753389; }"

var new = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "{", with: "")
new = new.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
new = new.replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "")
new = new.replacingOccurrences(of: ";", with: "")

print(new)
```

Obj-c:

```
NSString *str = @"{ Result1 = G; \"Result2\" = \"\"; Result3 = \"1.03\"; Result4 = 6212753389; }";

NSString *new = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
new = [new stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
new = [new stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@""];
new = [new stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", new);
```

add

> \n

for new lines.

Comment: can you write this code in objective c? because i m not good in swift and thank for reply

Comment: @RealmOfFire here you are :)